# Таймер в Python'e: протоколировать события, время которых должно сохраняться

Tags: python, таймер

Здравствуйте! Я только начинаю программировать в Python'е и мне нужно создать таймер. Суть программы в том, что запускается таймер и при работающем таймере нужно протоколировать определенные события, время которых должно сохраняться. То есть результат должен выглядить примерно так:

00:00:24:15 - комментарий Иванова

00:00:30:24 - говорит Сидоров

00:01:12:14 - пауза

Моих знаний пока не достаточно, чтобы самостоятельно создать такую программу. Кто-нибудь сможет помочь?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону logging и `{relativeCreative}` формат-кода, чтобы делать записи с отметкой времени, относительно старта программы.

Answer (score 1):

А у вас программа постоянно запущена? Как вариант - использовать time:

```
import time

# старт таймера
begin_time = time.time()

# выполняем продолжительное действие
time.sleep(1)

# получаем время окончания действия с начала запуска таймера
end_time = time.time()
print end_time - begin_time

# другое продолжительное действие
time.sleep(2)

# получаем время окончания действия с начала запуска таймера
end_time = time.time()
print end_time - begin_time
```

Выводит время в секундах, в минуты и часы перевести, надеюсь, сможете сами)

Если с переводом возникнут трудности, то [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms) как перевести секунды в минуты/часы

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использование qt:

```
import PyQt4

def timer_action():
    #делает, что надо каждую секунду как уже выше подсказали например

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
QtCore.QObject.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), timer_action)
timer.start(1000)
```